# How do I get java logging output to appear on a single line?

Tags: java, logging

At the moment a default entry looks something like this:

```
Oct 12, 2008 9:45:18 AM myClassInfoHere
INFO: MyLogMessageHere
```

How do I get it to do this?

```
Oct 12, 2008 9:45:18 AM myClassInfoHere - INFO: MyLogMessageHere
```

Clarification I'm using java.util.logging

Comment: I landed here because of adding Tomcat server to Eclipse. It seems Tomcat ignores the logging.properties so all answers below, except setting VM argument, failed. Actually this problem is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198899/tomcat-ignores-logging-properties-when-started-from-eclipse . Hope it helps someone :-)

Answer (score 95):

As of Java 7, [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29) supports getting its [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) from a system property, so adding something like this to the JVM command line will cause it to print on one line:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format='%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n'
```

Alternatively, you can also add this to your `logger.properties`:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format='%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n'
```

Comment: True as of Java7. There is no mention of this in the Java6 docs.

Comment: Also in IDEA, works with double quotes.   @jbruni This does not work in Java6.

Comment: Works with single quotes in Eclipse for me.

Comment: Instead of %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS you can write %1$tF %1$tT . Makes it a little bit shorter. I don't know if it's even faster.

Comment: ... or in `logging.properties`, with adaptation based on the suggestion by @BrunoEberhard and a shortened logger name:
 ```java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tF %1$tT %4$.1s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n```

Comment: If you use IntellIJ, you need to use double quotes. Single quotes didn't work for me.

Comment: Works better without quotes in logger.properties.

Comment: Trying to set this programmatically, I get this error "The field SimpleFormatter.format is not visible".

Answer (score 80):

Similar to Tervor, But I like to change the property  on runtime.

Note that this need to be set before the first SimpleFormatter is created - as was  written in the comments.

```
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", 
            "%1$tF %1$tT %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n");
```

Comment: Note that this need to be set before the first SimpleFormatter is created -  for example before getting global logger's handlers.

Comment: This is the quickest way to force your logs to write out to a single line without adding any other startup parameters to the JVM. But make sure you set this property before you make your call to 'new SimpleFormatter()' in your code.

Comment: FYI this pattern generates messages like this: `2022-03-16 13:40:04 INFORMATION org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
`

Answer (score 78):

### 1) `-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format`

Java 7 supports a property with the `java.util.Formatter` format string syntax.

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=...
```

See [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6381464).

My favorite is:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$-6s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n
```

which makes output like:

```
2014-09-02 16:44:57 SEVERE org.jboss.windup.util.ZipUtil unzip: Failed to load: foo.zip
```

### 2) Putting it to IDEs

IDEs typically let you set system properties for a project.
E.g. in NetBeans, instead of adding -D...=... somewhere, add the property in the action dialog, in a form of `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-...` - without any quotes. The IDE should figure out.

### 3) Putting that to Maven - Surefire

For your convenience, Here is how to put it to Surefire:

```xml
<!-- Surefire -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <!-- Set JUL Formatting -->
            <java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format>%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$-6s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n</java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

### 4) Hand-made

I have a library with [few `java.util.logging` related classes](http://code.google.com/p/ondrazizka/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FDwLib%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcz%2Fdynawest%2Flogging). Amongst them, it's `SingleLineFormatter`.
Downloadable jar [here](http://code.google.com/p/ondrazizka/source/browse/maven/cz/dynawest/lib/DwLib/1.01/DwLib-1.01-javadoc.jar).

```java
public class SingleLineFormatter extends Formatter {

  Date dat = new Date();
  private final static String format = "{0,date} {0,time}";
  private MessageFormat formatter;
  private Object args[] = new Object[1];

  // Line separator string.  This is the value of the line.separator
  // property at the moment that the SimpleFormatter was created.
  //private String lineSeparator = (String) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
  //        new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));
  private String lineSeparator = "\n";

  /**
   * Format the given LogRecord.
   * @param record the log record to be formatted.
   * @return a formatted log record
   */
  public synchronized String format(LogRecord record) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Minimize memory allocations here.
    dat.setTime(record.getMillis());    
    args[0] = dat;


    // Date and time 
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    if (formatter == null) {
      formatter = new MessageFormat(format);
    }
    formatter.format(args, text, null);
    sb.append(text);
    sb.append(" ");


    // Class name 
    if (record.getSourceClassName() != null) {
      sb.append(record.getSourceClassName());
    } else {
      sb.append(record.getLoggerName());
    }

    // Method name 
    if (record.getSourceMethodName() != null) {
      sb.append(" ");
      sb.append(record.getSourceMethodName());
    }
    sb.append(" - "); // lineSeparator



    String message = formatMessage(record);

    // Level
    sb.append(record.getLevel().getLocalizedName());
    sb.append(": ");

    // Indent - the more serious, the more indented.
    //sb.append( String.format("% ""s") );
    int iOffset = (1000 - record.getLevel().intValue()) / 100;
    for( int i = 0; i < iOffset;  i++ ){
      sb.append(" ");
    }


    sb.append(message);
    sb.append(lineSeparator);
    if (record.getThrown() != null) {
      try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        record.getThrown().printStackTrace(pw);
        pw.close();
        sb.append(sw.toString());
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: nicer memory consumption than the other solution.

Comment: I tried this - but it gives me the log in XML - what am I doing wrong - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030578/subclassing-java-util-logging-formatter-always-prints-xml

Comment: if it turns XML instead of the format you expected - that means the setting in your properties file did not found your formatter class, you can do 2 things: 1. make sure your class is in a package and set the formatter property to that class and package 2. make sure your class has a unique name like "MyFormatter", last: make sure all handlers have the formatter you wanted (java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=my.package.MyFormatter  and also:  java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=my.package.MyFormatter)

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I shared a Formatter I wrote in [response to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19991351/249623).  Its performed alright for me.  I like seeing the tricks other developers come up with for making code smaller and faster.

Comment: @ondra-Žižka For what its worth I just sent you a patch on your google code repo.

Comment: The google repo is off now... I'll be moving that to github.com/OndraZizka

Comment: Don't forget to use double quotes (at least in IntellIJ) when setting the formatter in the vm options.

Comment: @OndraŽižka Thank you very much, I customized your formatter a little bit so I'm not using your repo, but it's very didactic

Comment: How about the log level?

Answer (score 38):

Like Obediah Stane said, it's necessary to create your own `format` method. But I would change a few things:

- Create a subclass directly derived from `Formatter`, not from `SimpleFormatter`. The `SimpleFormatter` has nothing to add anymore.
- Be careful with creating a new `Date` object! You should make sure to represent the date of the `LogRecord`. When creating a new `Date` with the default constructor, it will represent the date and time the `Formatter` processes the `LogRecord`, not the date that the `LogRecord` was created.

The following class can be [used as formatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#setFormatter(java.util.logging.Formatter)) in a `Handler`, which in turn can be [added](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)) to the `Logger`. Note that it ignores all class and method information available in the `LogRecord`.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public final class LogFormatter extends Formatter {

    private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(new Date(record.getMillis()))
            .append(" ")
            .append(record.getLevel().getLocalizedName())
            .append(": ")
            .append(formatMessage(record))
            .append(LINE_SEPARATOR);

        if (record.getThrown() != null) {
            try {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                record.getThrown().printStackTrace(pw);
                pw.close();
                sb.append(sw.toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this - but it gives me the log in XML - what am I doing wrong - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030578/subclassing-java-util-logging-formatter-always-prints-xml

Comment: if it turns XML instead of the format you expected - that means the setting in your properties file did not found your formatter class, you can do 2 things: 1. make sure your class is in a package and set the formatter property to that class and package 2. make sure your class has a unique name like "MyFormatter", last: make sure all handlers have the formatter you wanted (java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=my.package.MyFormatter  and also:  java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=my.package.MyFormatter)

Answer (score 12):

This is what I'm using.

```java
public class VerySimpleFormatter extends Formatter {

    private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";

    @Override
    public String format(final LogRecord record) {
        return String.format(
                "%1$s %2$-7s %3$s\n",
                new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN).format(
                        new Date(record.getMillis())),
                record.getLevel().getName(), formatMessage(record));
    }
}
```

You'll get something like...

```
2016-08-19T17:43:14.295+09:00 INFO    Hey~
2016-08-19T17:43:16.068+09:00 SEVERE  Seriously?
2016-08-19T17:43:16.068+09:00 WARNING I'm warning you!!!
```

Comment: How could we have this formatter output exception information, such as its stacktrace?

Comment: @fegemo I think you can print the starcktrace like this. `ofNullable(record.getThrown()).ifPresent(v -> v.printStackTrace());` just before return the formatted message.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Eclipse config]

Per screenshot, in Eclipse select "run as" then "Run Configurations..." and add the answer from Trevor Robinson with double quotes instead of quotes. If you miss the double quotes you'll get "could not find or load main class" errors.

Comment: As per the previous answer, this works in Java 7.   Java 6 doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Thank you, it had to be this way, the logging.properties does not work for Eclipse console, for some reason!

Answer (score 5):

I've figured out a way that works. You can subclass SimpleFormatter and override the format method

```
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return new java.util.Date() + " " + record.getLevel() + " " + record.getMessage() + "\r\n";
    }
```

A bit surprised at this API I would have thought that more functionality/flexibility would have been provided out of the box

Comment: Anyone should use `formatMessage(record)` rather than `record.getMessage()`. Place holders won't changed.

Answer (score -2):

If you log in a web application using tomcat add:

```
-Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
```

On VM arguments

Answer (score -3):

This logging is specific to your application and not a general Java feature. What application(s) are you running?

It might be that this is coming from a specific logging library that you are using within your own code. If so, please post the details of which one you are using.

Comment: It's not some random logger application. It's java's own `java.util.logging.Logger`

Answer (score -3):

if you're using java.util.logging, then there is a configuration file that is doing this to log contents (unless you're using programmatic configuration).  So, your options are 
1) run post -processor that removes the line breaks
2) change the log configuration AND remove the line breaks from it. Restart your application (server) and you should be good.