# How do I suppress the date line from 2-line java.util.logging output?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm using the Java default logger, and right now it's printing a lot of useless trash to the output, here is a example, this line of code:

```
log.info("Logging pointless information...")
```

Will output all of this:

```
Oct 26, 2011 9:37:57 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: Logging pointless information...
```

I don't need to know anything except that second line. How can I remove this trash? All I want is simple text logging.

Comment: FWIW, that "useless information" is very useful in a program of any size or duration.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Personally, I'm a fan of logging tersely to console and verbosely to file (with an XML formatter). So I think both forms have great merit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [create a a different Formatter](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18515.html) and use it instead.

```
public class BriefFormatter extends Formatter 
{   
    public BriefFormatter() { super(); }

    @Override 
    public String format(final LogRecord record) 
    {
        return record.getMessage();
    }   
}
```

Comment: This approach logs the entire raw record, including XML.  Actually much more verbose than SimpleFormatter.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe this was added later, but at least with Java 7, java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter supports getting its format from a system property. This JVM argument will print just the second line:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format='%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n'
```

Personally, I like to keep all the date/source info, but get rid of the newline (and use a more compact, international date format):

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format='%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n'
```

Comment: You seriously have no idea how much better you just made my life.  This saved me at least 5 hours of work, on account of not familiar with java.

Comment: Thousands of little babies and little kittens and little baby kittens have been saved due to your answer here today. Thankful appreciation is in order.

Answer (score 3):

These are asking pretty much the same question:

- [How do I get java logging output to appear on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194765/how-do-i-get-java-logging-output-to-appear-on-a-single-line)
- [java.util.logging: how to suppress date line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950704/java-util-logging-how-to-suppress-date-line)

Here's an example of how to implement Jarrod Roberson's suggestion: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18515.html

In general, to apply a formatter you create a file, usually called logging.properties. In it put a line like this:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

or whatever your formatter class is. Then add a JVM arg like this:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

Or use a more powerful logging system, like Logback or Log4j, which have prebuilt formatters to save you some coding.