# java.util.logging: Remove date time line

Tags: java, logging

I currently have this code in my main().

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("My Log");
FileHandler fh;
logger.addHandler(fh);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(formatter);
logger.info("Test");
```

This outputs 2 lines. One with datetime, and the other is test. I read many other questions on this site, but i do not get how to implement it to my current code.

UPDATE: I have created a new file called logging.properties and updated Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("logging.properties");

Inside the file i inputted these values

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
javax.jms.connection.level = INFO
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tr] %3$s %4$s:  %5$s %n
```

But when i run i still see the date line. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it programatically, you could do 2 things:

- Implement a custom formatter and set to handler: `fh.setFormatter(new MyCustomFormatter());` See http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/logging/create-custom-formatter-for-logger-handler/
- If you want only 1 line, the workaround is explained here: 
  [java.util.logging: how to suppress date line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950704/java-util-logging-how-to-suppress-date-line)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file called `logging.properties` to your Java project. In there, you can define the format to be used:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tr] %3$s %4$s:  %5$s %n
```

The documentation here explains what the `%...` specifiers mean: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax