# Why java.util.logging is displaying wrong class when I log a message

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am testing `java.util.logging` and it is displaying wrong class when I log a message. This is my code:

I have an interface **MyLogger**:

```
package ptest2;

public interface MyLogger {
    public void info(String message);
}
```

I have an implementation class **MyLoggerImpl** which implements interface `MyLogger` using `java.util.logging`:

```
package ptest2;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyLoggerImpl implements MyLogger { 
    private Logger logger;

    public MyLoggerImpl(String name) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
    }   

    @Override
    public void info(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

I have a class **MyLoggerFactory** which has a static method that accepts a `String name` parameter and give `MyLogger`:

```
package ptest2;

public class MyLoggerFactory {
    public static MyLogger getMyLogger(String name) {
        MyLogger myLogger = new MyLoggerImpl(name);
        return myLogger;
    }
}
```

Now I create a class **ClientClass2** which uses logging. It has a method which will display a INFO level message:

```
package ptest2;

public class ClientClass2 {
    private static MyLogger LOGGER = MyLoggerFactory.getMyLogger("ClientClass2");

    public void method2() {
        LOGGER.info("This is INFO level message");
    }
}
```

To test it I create a class **TestLoggingClientClass2**:

```
package ptest2;

public class TestLoggingClientClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientClass2 clientClass2 = new ClientClass2();

        clientClass2.method2();
    }
}
```

I run it and this is what I got:

> 10-Apr-2015 12:17:18 PM ptest2.MyLoggerImpl info 
> INFO: This is INFO
>   level message

But this is what I should have got:

> 10-Apr-2015 12:17:18 PM ptest2.ClientClass2 info 
> INFO: This is INFO
>   level message

I dont see any problem with the code. What I am doing wrong? How can I get the required results?

## UPDATE

The other questions are for formatting the message. But I am ok with the format of the message. My concern is why the message is displaying the wrong class.

I have look at the source code of the `java.util.logging` (Thank you Oracle).

The message is formatted by `public synchronized String format(LogRecord record)` method of `SimpleFormatter` class. For the class name, this method uses `sourceClassName` property of the concerned `LogRecord`; and only if that property is null then it uses `loggerName` property of the concerned `LogRecord`

In the `Logger` class, when the `public void info(String msg)` method is called then it sets the `loggerName` property of the concerned `LogRecord`.

In the `Logger` class, when the `public void logp(Level level, String sourceClass, String sourceMethod, String msg)` method is called then it sets the `sourceClassName` property of the concerned `LogRecord`.

So in **MyLoggerImpl** class instead of me calling

```
@Override
public void info(String message) {
    logger.info(message);
}
```

I change to

```
@Override
public void info(String message) {
    logger.logp(Level.INFO, logger.getName(), "info", message);
}
```

and it work. Strange. What do you guys make of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure the jdk14 logging's pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416769/how-to-configure-the-jdk14-loggings-pattern)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194765/how-do-i-get-java-logging-output-to-appear-on-a-single-line and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950704/java-util-logging-how-to-suppress-date-line for more discussion about changing the message format.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.logging.Logger` is invoked from `MyLoggerImpl`, that's why its name is printed. To check this you can for test use it from `ClientClass2` directly and then (and only then) it will print `ptest2.ClientClass2`.

BTW I don't know why you're creating your own Logger API, take a look at slf2j or logback, no point in reinventing the wheel.

UPDATE: You've updated the logger to use `logger name` where a `class name` is expected as parameter for `logp` method so it's being printed like that according to current logging pattern. You can either follow this approach or change the pattern. In the former case you could change `MyLoggerFactory` to accept `Class<?>` parameter:

```
public static MyLogger getMyLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
    return new MyLoggerImpl(clazz.getSimpleName());
}
```

Comment: So what is the point of `String name` argument to `Logger.getLogger(String name)` method of `java.util.logging`?

Comment: @srh it's an identity of the logger. You can get the same logger from different places using this name.