# Some issues with java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, logging

I have the following example code :

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggingExample {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(
    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName() );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
      LOGGER.info("Logging an INFO-level message");
      LOGGER.fine("Logging an INFO-level message2");

    }
}
```

With the output to console of:

```
05/06/2014 12:07:09 ztesting.Loger.LoggingExample main
INFO: Logging an INFO-level message
```

And I have several question:

1. The entire output is in red, can I set the output to be in different colors according to the level?
2. Can I not display the first line "05/06/2014 12:07:09 ztesting.Loger.LoggingExample main"
3. Can I block the output to console completely, meaning I would only set output to a log file.
4. Not as important, but why does the fine row does not display ?

P.S.  I m using netbeans 6.9

ALSO tried using the following links and it got me no where

[Is there any way to remove the information line from java.util.logging.Logger output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304784/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-information-line-from-java-util-logging-logger-ou)

[How do I get java logging output to appear on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304784/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-information-line-from-java-util-logging-logger-ou)

Thanks for any help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your questions are answered in different tutorials available for `java.util.logging`. One example [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/index.html)

You should also read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html).

```
"Can I not display the first line "05/06/2014 12:07:09 ztesting.Loger.LoggingExample main"
```

Yes, using [Formatters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html)

```
"Can I block the output to console completely, meaning I would only set output to a log file."
```

Yes, set the log level, filter or handler in a [configuration](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html#configuration-file) file

```
"The entire output is in red, can I set the output to be in different colors according to the level?"
```

This is specific to Netbeans which I don't personally use so I can't answer that.

Personally I prefer [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) with [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch) over JUL...