# java.util.logging won't use custom formatter

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have created my own formatter, extending java.util.logging.Formatter.

My logging.properties looks like:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=path.to.my.MyFormatter
```

However, whenever I run it, MyFormatter is never constructed, and never invoked.

Running it with the -verbose option I have verified that path.to.my.MyFormatter is loaded shortly after java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is loaded, so I don't think it is a class path problem.

If it is relevant (I hope not) I am running on a RedHat6.4 server with openjdk-1.6.0.

W

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030578/subclassing-java-util-logging-formatter-doesnt-work

Comment: The simpleDateFormat string I entered was invalid.  Because it was defined inline for a final, it never got to my debug message in the constructor, and java.util.logging silently ignored the exception.