# Custom Charactor in log4j ConversionPattern in Struts2

Tags: struts2, log4j, struts, log4j2

I am implementin log4j with struts2.

`<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n" />`

and I am calling like from in my action.

```
logger.info("<p>SMS sent to XXXXXXXX </p>");
```

It's working fine. The result is

`2013-11-18 10:09:23 SMSLogger [INFO] <p> SMS sent to XXXXXXXX</p>`

But I want to write like  below

`<p>2013-11-18 10:09:23 SMSLogger [INFO] SMS sent to XXXXXXXX</p>`

I want this to do some format in web design.

Is there a way by include this in the log4j ConversionPattern ? 
Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, i would suggest you to handle this html paragraph element through your front end (html/jsp). If not then you can try out the custom formatter from logger as mentioned in the below URLs.

- [subclassing-java-util-logging-formatter-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030578/subclassing-java-util-logging-formatter-doesnt-work)
- [create-custom-formatter-for-logger-handler](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/logging/create-custom-formatter-for-logger-handler/)

Comment: Thanks. i already made as you said only. like below I `$.get('log/log.txt', function(data) {
  $("#logTxt").html("");
  var lines = (data).split("\n");
  for ( var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
   ($("<p>").text(lines[i])).appendTo($("#logTxt"));
}
 });`