# Configure logging in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am using java logging in Groovy and I wanted to modify the format string so I only have one line instead of two, but the methods I tried didn't work - I looked at this question:

[How do I get java logging output to appear on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194765/how-do-i-get-java-logging-output-to-appear-on-a-single-line)

I tried passing the property to groovy, but it didn't change the format.

I passed it like this:

`groovy myScript.groovy -Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tF %1$tT`

but it doesn't look like it was picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did - I added this code to my groovy:

```
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format",
 '%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$-6s %5$s%6$s%n');
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("")
    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("../log/replication.log")
    log.addHandler(fh)
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter()
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
```

which didn't require me to modify the java properties in command line (I didn't want to create additional script to start my groovy script).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JAVA_OPTS` for that. For example,

```
import java.util.logging.*

Logger log = Logger.getLogger('test')
log.setLevel(Level.INFO)

log.info('Test info log')
log.warning('Test warning')
log.config('Test config')
log.fine('Test fine')
```

and setting (i.e. below for windows):

`set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tF %1$tT [%4$s] %5$s %n"`

Running the above sample script yields:

```
> groovy testLoggingJavaUtil.groovy
2015-03-27 17:35:48 [INFO] Test info log
2015-03-27 17:35:48 [WARNING] Test warning
```