# Tomcat ignores logging.properties when started from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'd like to enable Tomcat logging and changed `Tomcat/conf/logging.properties` (I enabled `org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE`)

However, when I start Tomcat from Eclipse, it ignores my settings and shows logs as before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomcat that is started from Eclipse uses configuration that is specified in its Properties. By default, logging configuration is not specified.

So, `open Eclipse -> select Tomcat -> Properties`, click `Open Launch configuration`and in `Arguments` tab add `-Djava.util.logging.config.file="your-tomcat-folder\conf\logging.properties" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`.