# Eclipse Tomcat logging config file

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging

I have a Tomcat 9 server configured in Eclipse Oxygen. I am trying to use the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` file of my Tomcat install. According to [Eclipse Tomcat FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_enable_the_JULI_logging_in_a_Tomcat_5.5_Server_instance.3F), I need to:

1) Copy the `logging.properties` file in the server Configuration path folder in Eclipse (here `workspace/Servers/Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost-config`)

2) Put the following VM arguments in the server configuration:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="<put catalina.base path here>/conf/logging.properties"
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

So first question: aren't these two instructions contradictory? Why would I bother to copy the file in my workspace if I'm going to use the original file in the VM argument?

Anyway, it does not work at all. In `logging.properties` I defined a Logger with a FINE level which is not taken into account, whereas it is when I run Tomcat outside of Eclipse. How do I make it work in Eclipse? How can I check which file is loaded?

**EDIT**

The Eclipse Tomcat FAQ says it's for Tomcat 5.5 but I am unable to find the same doc for Tomcat 9. Besides, the `catalina.bat` script confirms these are the two parameters to set for logging :

```
set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

The [Tomcat 9 documentation on logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html) only says the following on the matter:

> This java.util.logging implementation is enabled by providing certain
>   system properties when starting Java. The Apache Tomcat startup
>   scripts do this for you, but if you are using different tools to run
>   Tomcat (such as jsvc, or running Tomcat from within an IDE), you
>   should take care of them by yourself.

Comment: Your question is referring to documentation for Tomcat 5.5, which was released in 2004, but you are running Tomcat 9. Here is the [correct logging documentation for Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html). Update or withdraw your question as appropriate.

Comment: @skomisa thanks for your answer. I read the Tomcat 9 doc before posting, it is not helping. I edited my post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat ignores logging.properties when started from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198899/tomcat-ignores-logging-properties-when-started-from-eclipse)