# Configuring logs with Tomcat 8.5 / Eclipse 4.7 / Java 8 causes startup failure

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, java.util.logging

Attempting to configure different logging setups for an installation of Tomcat 8.5 so that I can have different log details for different projects.

I've set up Eclipse 4.7 with the option for tomcat configuration files in the workspace, and because it doesn't create a `logging.properties` file (unlike most of the rest of the tomcat config files) I copied the `logging.properties` from $CATALINA_HOME/conf to the same location as the other files and changed it to enable the additional detail I require.  This change was ignored, presumably because the core tomcat config file is still being used.

Following the advice at [Tomcat ignores logging.properties when started from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198899/tomcat-ignores-logging-properties-when-started-from-eclipse) I added

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="F:\eclipse workspaces\myprojectname\Servers\Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config\logging.properties"
```

to the arguments list in the server launch configuration dialog.

When starting the server now, I get the following errors:

```
Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1165)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:349)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.addHandler(LogManager.java:1655)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:980)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1165)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:349)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
Can't load log handler "2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.addHandler(LogManager.java:1655)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:980)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1165)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:349)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
Can't load log handler "3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.addHandler(LogManager.java:1655)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:980)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1165)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:349)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
Can't load log handler "4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.addHandler(LogManager.java:1655)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:980)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1165)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:349)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
```

The server starts up correctly other than this, but it seems some of the logging options applied are being ignored, e.g. the default log format is being used rather than the more friendly format that usually appears in the console output.  It appears as though the configuration is being interpreted as a standard java.util.logging configuration, not the enhanced JULI variant normally used by Tomcat.

How do I persuade Tomcat/JULI to understand this configuration file when launched via Eclipse?

Comment: Did you also add `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager` ?

Comment: @Selaron - no, and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: You have been soo close ;-0